# Override transitive dependency - Maven

Tags: maven

Below is the dependency from my project

```
[INFO] |  +- jasperreports:jasperreports:jar:3.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jfree:jcommon:jar:1.0.15:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jfree:jfreechart:jar:1.0.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.02:compile
```

How can I override jasperreports to include  xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.3.04? 
I see exclude which I am not interested in as I do not want to exclude xml-apis.

So what is the syntax to override transitive dependency?

Answer (score 3):

I tried the following and it worked

1. In the parent POM

```xml
    <properties>
    <!-- Xml Apis -->
    <xml-apis.version>1.3.04</xml-apis.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                <version>${xml-apis.version}</version>
            </dependency>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

2. In project POM

```xml
   <dependency>
       <groupId>jasperreports</groupId>
       <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
       <version>3.1.4</version>
    </dependency>

   <dependency>
        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>           
   </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the above, having only **Point 1** contents and ignoring **Point 2** contents also works